# Print int array with "and" before last element

Tags: java

The following is for one of my assignments in my java programming class. I have all the code written already I just can't figure how to make the output display what i need it to display.

For my assignment I have to write a program with a single-dimension array that holds 10 integer numbers between 1 and 100 and sort the array using a bubble sort.

An example of what the output needs to look like is this:

The unsorted list is: 54, 27, 13, 97, 5, 63, 78, 34, 47, **and 81**
The sorted list is: 5, 13, 27, 34, 47, 54, 63, 78, 81, **and 97**

My output is displaying this:
The unsorted list is: 54, 27, 13, 97, 5, 63, 78, 34, 47, 81,
The sorted list is: 5, 13, 27, 34, 47, 54, 63, 78, 81, 97,

I can't figure out how to write the `"and"` into the output.

```
public class Chpt7_Project {
/** The method for sorting the numbers */
public static void bubbleSort(int[] numbers) 
  {
    int temp;

      for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
         {
           if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) 
           {
           temp = numbers[j]; // swap number[i] with number[j]
           numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
           numbers[j + 1] = temp;
           }
         }
      }
   }
public static void main(String[] args) { // Test Method

    System.out.print("The unsorted list is: ");
    // Generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 100
    int[] numbers = new int[10]; 

    for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
        numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100); 
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    bubbleSort (numbers); // numbers are sorted from smallest to largest
    System.out.print("The sorted list is: ");
    for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
    }
}


}
```

Comment: What have you tried to modify that final for loop of the main method? You've got a trailing comma, as well, so figuring that out will get you close on when to add the "and"

Comment: I would modify the for loop to `numbers.length - 1` and after the loop you can print `"and " + numbers.Last` or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps a simple if-else will help you here?

Comment: Check your `for` loop. You could add an `if` that checks if you are at the second-to-last or at the last element and trigger some different behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this loop

```
for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
    System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
}
```

to

```
for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
    if(i== numbers.length-1) {
        System.out.println("and "+numbers[i]);
    } else {
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Still has a trailing comma

Comment: a comma is needed before "and"

Answer (score 0):

Output:

```
The unsorted list is: 67, 86, 78, 80, 56, 45, 24, 2, 67, and 98

The sorted list is: 2, 24, 45, 56, 67, 67, 78, 80, 86, and 98
```

Modified Code(Integrated what @abhinav mentioned):

```
public class Chpt7_Project {
/** The method for sorting the numbers */
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] numbers) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) {
                   temp = numbers[j]; // swap number[i] with number[j]
                   numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                   numbers[j + 1] = temp;
               }
             }
          }
       }

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Test Method

        System.out.print("The unsorted list is: ");
        // Generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 100
        int[] numbers = new int[10]; 
        for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            if(i== numbers.length-1) {
                System.out.println("and "+numbers[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        bubbleSort (numbers); // numbers are sorted from smallest to largest
        System.out.print("The sorted list is: ");
        for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
            if(i== numbers.length-1) {
                System.out.println("and "+numbers[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```